# How use canvas from external video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<title>Video/Canvas Gray Effect</title> 
<script> 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var v = document.getElementById('v');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var back = document.createElement('canvas');
    var backcontext = back.getContext('2d');

    var cw,ch;

    v.addEventListener('play', function(){
        cw = v.clientWidth;
        ch = v.clientHeight;
        canvas.width = cw;
        canvas.height = ch;
        back.width = cw;
        back.height = ch;
        draw(v,context,backcontext,cw,ch);
    },false);

},false);

function draw(v,c,bc,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    // First, draw it into the backing canvas
    bc.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
    var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var data = idata.data;
    // Loop through the pixels, turning them grayscale
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
        var r = data[i];
        var g = data[i+1];
        var b = data[i+2];
        var brightness = (3*r+4*g+b)>>>3;
        data[i] = brightness;
        data[i+1] = brightness;
        data[i+2] = brightness;
    }
    idata.data = data;
    // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
    c.putImageData(idata,0,0);
    // Start over!
    setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,bc,w,h);
}
</script> 



<video id=v controls loop> 
    <source src=video.webm type=video/webm> 
</video> 
<canvas id=c></canvas> 

<style> 
#c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -180px 0 0 20px;
}

#v {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -180px 0 0 -500px;
}
</style>
```

The canvas work only if the video hosted in my site, but if a external video the canvas not working only work if make a proxy using the same domain, for example:

Working if a hosted the video on my site:

```
   <video id=v controls loop> 
        <source src=video.webm type=video/webm> 
    </video>
```

Working if a use a proxy, but I will not use a proxy:

```
<video id=v controls loop> 
        <source src=./proxy.php?url_toexternal_video=http://host.com/video.webm type=video/webm> 
    </video>
```

Not working if a use the direct link to the video:

```
<video id=v controls loop> 
        <source src=http://host.com/video.webm type=video/webm> 
</video>
```

any way to make it work if it is from an external video? Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there's no way to use `getImageData` on a canvas that has been tainted by cross-origin content.